# Spring Boot create @Bean based on @Values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I want to get values from my application.properties from spring.datasource.* fields but those fields are null.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class DatabaseConfig {

@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String url;
@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String username;
@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String password;

@Bean(name = "database_url")
public String getDatabaseUrl() {
    return url+"?user="+username+"&password="+password;
}
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/endlessblow_db
spring.datasource.username=kuba
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

this db in url is my docker postgre container host and it works fine.

**EDIT**
DatabaseConnection.java

```
public class DatabaseConnection {

    private String databaseUrl;

    @Autowired
    void setDatabaseUrl(@Qualifier("database_url") String databaseUrl) {
        this.databaseUrl = databaseUrl;
    }

    private static DatabaseConnection instance;
    private Connection connection;

    private DatabaseConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Database Connection Creation Failed : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public static DatabaseConnection getInstance() throws SQLException, URISyntaxException, IOException {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseConnection();
        } else if (instance.getConnection().isClosed()) {
            instance = new DatabaseConnection();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this code? Thank you!

Comment: Please add to the description also the `application.properties` file.

Comment: is the application properties located in `src/main/resources` ? I feel its not read correctly.
also this config class must be under package hierachy of the main springbootapplication class.

Comment: Why? Feels like you are working around the autoconfiguration available, what is it you are trying to achieve that isn't possible with the auto configuration?

Comment: i can help with this please ping me

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons `@Value` annotated fields are not initialized I guess.  try sending values as `@Bean` method params.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class DatabaseConfig {

 @Bean(name = "database_url")
 public String getDatabaseUrl(@Value("${spring.datasource.url}") String url,
  @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")String username,
  @Value("${spring.datasource.password}") String password
  ) {
    return url+"?user="+username+"&password="+password;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! All right I will try this out once I'm out of bath

Comment: unfortunately nothing changed, but I have added (edited post) the class in which I use this bean, maybe here lays the problem?

Comment: @Jawegiel how is  `DatabaseConnection` initialized?

Answer (score 0):

`String` is immutable class, meaning each time a new `String` is created normally a new `String` *might* be created in the string pool and a new reference *might* be returned.

For this reason you can't have `String` object as a bean in your application context.

```
@Bean(name = "database_url")
public String getDatabaseUrl() {  <----------------The return type of String is wrong
    return url+"?user="+username+"&password="+password;
}
```

So just create a custom object in this `@Bean` method which could be transferred and used in the application context

Why not return a `DatabaseConnection` from that `@Bean` method this would seem the optimal solution in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new file where you 2st read data from property file

```
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public class DatabaseLoginProperties{
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

----Now above value you can uses in your java file -------------------

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DatabaseLoginProperties databaseLoginProperties;
    @Bean
    public String getDatabaseUrl() {
        return databaseLoginProperties.getUrl()+"?user="+databaseLoginProperties.getUsername()+"&password="+databaseLoginProperties.getPassword();
    }
}
```

Comment: you understand that a String is immutable and can't be registered as bean in application context right? Check my answer bellow

Comment: yes you correct bro